# Pythonic way to extract first line of a tabular file to a list

Tags: python

This is a function that takes the tabular file as input and return the first row as list:

```
def firstline_to_list(fvar):
    """
    Input tab separated file.
    Output first row as list.
    """
    import csv
    lineno = 0
    with open(fvar, 'r') as tsvfile:
        tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in tabreader:
            lineno += 1
            if lineno == 1:
                return row
                break
```

Is there a better way to do it than this clunky code of mine?

Comment: `break` after `return row` won't be reached never, so you can delete it.

Comment: FYI "Pythonesque" generally means "reminiscent of the work of Monty Python". The term you are looking for is likely "Pythonic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your for loop with a single call of `next` on the iterator `tabreader`. In python 2.7, this should be `tabreader.next()`, and in python 3, I think it's `next(tabreader)`. You might also want to wrap the call in `try except` block for `StopIteration` exception, just in case the file is empty.

So putting everything together, here's version that's compatible with python 2 and 3:

```
def firstline_to_list(fvar):
    """
    Input tab separated file.
    Output first row as list.
    """
    import csv, sys

    with open(fvar, 'r') as tsvfile:
        tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
        try:
            if sys.version > '3':
                result = next(tabreader)
            else:
                result = tabreader.next()
        except StopIteration:
            result = None

    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

The absolute minimum modification to your code would be this:

```
def firstline_to_list(fvar):
    """
    Input tab separated files.
    Output first row as list.
    """
    import csv
    with open(fvar, 'r') as tsvfile:
        tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in tabreader:
            return row
```

A better way would be to use `Reader.next()` as documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
def firstline_to_list(fvar):
    """
    Input tab separated files.
    Output first row as list.
    """
    import csv
    with open(fvar, 'r') as tsvfile:
        tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
        return tabreader.next()
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
import pandas
return list(pandas.read_csv(fvar,sep='\t',nrows=1))
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Although this introduces extra dependency on pandas, and not necessary when just need to read the first line, it could prove useful if ppl want to a large number of rows, since pandas csv reader is much more efficient than the python csv library.